# FCM still using registration token for sending notificationo like GCM?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm new in FCM and I have a (may be) stupid questions.

**Does FCM still using the registration toke like GCM?**

**Does FCM use registration token with Google Play ?**

**Does FCM registration token periodic change?** I saw this answer in another post and I think is like GCM

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does FCM still using the registration toke like GCM?

Yes.

> Does FCM use registration token with Google Play ?

Not sure what you mean here.

> Does FCM registration token periodic change?

Yes, under certain conditions managed by the internal FCM service.